# Placing popup window at the bottom right corner of main window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to place a popup window at the bottom right corner of the main window .It should be visible there even the main window got resized/expanded.
How can I do that in Qt 5.9 (in C++)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are trying to run?

Comment: In SO it is highly valued that the author of the question shows what he tries to solve his problem. You could show me what you've tried.

Comment: You should resize the popup manually when the main window is resized, see [`resizeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important task in your question is to move the popup when the QMainWindow is resized or moved, for this we must override the `resizeEvent` and `moveEvent` method. the following code shows how to do it:

```
void MainWindow::movePopUp()
{
    QPoint p = mapToGlobal(QPoint(size().width(), size().height())) -
            QPoint(popup->size().width(), popup->size().height());
    popup->move(p);
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    movePopUp();
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}

void MainWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event)
{
    movePopUp();
    QMainWindow::moveEvent(event);
}
```

Output:

[image]

The complete example is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/PopUpExample)

Comment: Hi eyllanesc,Thanks for the code.I have tried it and worked well.still I have some doubts.Initially,the popup window was showed outside the main window.And when I tried to replace or resize the main window,the popup comes inside it .Why so ? I have to display the pop up window inside the main window from the beginning itself. And I have one more question,where I can set a timer for the popup window ?

Comment: You could show me a video of what you get, I do not understand when you mean the popup is out.

Comment: What do you want to do with the timer?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/SIPLA/Desktop/NOTIFICATION.htm

Comment: Please go through the above link.I have shown how the output displayed. By using the the timer,I have to hide the popup window after few seconds of display.

Comment: what is this:  
file:///C:/Users/SIPLA/Desktop/NOTIFICATION.htm?

Comment: You are sending me a link regarding a file that is on your pc.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.I have tried your code and it worked now.To set timer 
 I just had to use "  QTimer::singleShot(tim*1000, &qPopup, &QLabel::hide);"